# Does a package installed from repository in 14.04 work after upgrading to 16.04? Do the updates work too?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, dpkg

What happens when a package is installed using a repository in Ubuntu 14.04 and the distribution is upgraded to 16.04?

Does the package remain functional or can it break (assuming the package maintainers do not yet support 16.04)

What happens during the update/upgrade process if the package does not have Ubuntu 16.04 repositories?

What if the package repository exists for Ubuntu 16.04 can it be updated/upgraded as normal or are there additional steps involved such as manual updating the sources list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try my best to answer this:

> What happens when a package is installed using a repository in Ubuntu
> 14.04 and the distribution is upgraded to 16.04?
>
> Does the package remain functional or can it break (assuming the
> package maintainers do not yet support 16.04)

The package will remain functional unless the new version 16.04 upgraded some dependencies (like libraries) that now causes the package to break or have weird behavior.

> What happens during the update/upgrade process if the package does not
> have Ubuntu 16.04 repositories?

If you try to update that package but the new version does not exist on any of your repositories, then the package will not be updated.

> What if the package repository exists for Ubuntu 16.04 can it be
> updated/upgraded as normal or are there additional steps involved such
> as manual updating the sources list?

Usually it can be normally updated, unless the new version brings some new specific steps you have to do (like new dependencies that are not on the official repositories and such).

Comment: What happens to application which rely on init and the os is upgraded to systemd? Do those settings get migrated across or do they have to be updated manually?

Comment: I would say they have to be manually updated, unless the developer provides a systemd update in a newer version